# Should questions with obstacle ";" ( eg:if(n>0); ) as answers be closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Sometimes I would found some questions which the answer is just the OP added an excessive ";" after some code and then skip the next code, but I remember some were closed while some were not.

Today I have some time to find those questions, some are closed but some are not (To OP below: sorry to bring your questions to meta as example!):

Currently not closed:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891848)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045557)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265261)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861325)

Currently closed:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815489)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969844)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697351)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051171)

---

My question is not focusing on the questions above and not arguing whether they should be closed or not, just want to know the criteria for a question to meet the closed reason "cannot be reproduced". Does it depend on answer? Or just depend on question?

And one more question to this: if I asked those types of questions accidently, should I delete it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the question's problem boils down to a legitimate typo, vote to close it as such.  The first example doesn't quite rise to the occasion, as there's more to the problem than *just* a semicolon in the wrong place.  You want to evaluate the question on its merits before you look around at the answers it has.

If you ask one of those questions, it's probably not worth keeping around; that is, if it was *just* a typo, it's likely not going to be one of those things that would help anyone else out, so deleting it may be a good option.

Comment: Yes, there's slightly more than a semicolon in the wrong place, there's a missing `if` too. Still a typo. Aside from that, I concurr.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think the "simple typographical error" reason quite applies here. There is more going on here than, for example, if someone had use the wrong variable in a calculation or putting the wrong type of brace or bracket.

That being said, I'm not suggesting such questions should stay open. Instead, there should be a canonical question for this problem (or possibly one for each language that gets a lot of them), and new instances of it should be duped against it.

Either way: the question gets closed, and potentially down the track deleted. I think fairly much everyone agrees on that. I only disagree on the best close reason.

I think the distinction between being an off topic typo and duping against a canonical question comes down to: does a comment saying "change `...;` to `...` (remove the semicolon)" *fully* answer the problem? If it does, it's a typo; but if it it's not necessarily obvious (particularly to someone just learning the language) *why* that loose semicolon causes that problem (and why removing it is the right solution), then it benefits from having a full answer.

Even when a question is clearly going to be closed and unlikely to help future visitors, I think we should do our best to help an OP who has made a genuine effort at asking a good question (remembering that this problem can give errors that aren't very searchable). If that can't be done in a comment because the explanation is a little deeper than "you typed the wrong thing", then the best thing for them is to be pointed at the canonical question and explanation.

> if I asked those types of questions accidently, should I delete it?

Yes. If you realise a question you've asked is a dup (that doesn't add any potential 'signpost' value) - or if you realise it is off-topic - then deleting it is the right thing to do.

Comment: The point about the typo reason is that it does not come down to "is that a real typo, or only a bit like a typo". Instead it is "is this question going to be any use to anyone else?" If there is no way at all that a beginner can have a clue as to what an "empty" block is in a particular language, then perhaps it is worthwhile. But is that likely?

Comment: @Bill it's not just about knowing what an empty block is, but why one appears in this context - a beginner (especially a beginner to C/C++/Java but with some background in, say, CSS) could conceivably expect "empty block" to always be spelled `{}`. I think the "is this question going to be any use to anyone else" test is good for deciding whether the question should stay open - I don't think it should, and I've edited my answer to make it clearer that that's not what I'm arguing.